# Heroku, Play Framework 2.0 runs, but javascript or CSS not showing

Tags: java, javascript, heroku, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm quite new to using and deploying Play to heroku!

Yes it works deploying and my Procfile looks like this:

> web: target/universal/stage/bin/appdude -Dhttp.port=${PORT}

However, when I'm running my framework on heroku, it displays only the text and not the fancy UI (javascript, css.....).
So I'm just wondering if anyone knows what I'm missing?

I've followed the instruction on :
http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.1/ProductionHeroku.

But still, it occurs :(

**Running on localhost:**

[image: Running on localhost:9000]

**Running on heroku:**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ach, use `play start` on localhost and you will see exactly the same as on Heroku!

Play Welcome screen displays ONLY in development mode, go to the `app/views/index.scala.html` file. Replace the `@play20.welcome(message, style = "Java")` method call with your own HTML and start developing.

Tip: there's no any single character in `main.css` right after app creation, whole code is perfectly blank (if we don't count this welcome screen which is included from sources).

**Good news** is that you deployed your first application to Heroku and it started as expected what can be proved by **Your new application is ready** message ;)